# Are functions of the form $f(x)=A\sin(x)+B\cos(x)$ the only ones satisfying $f'(x)=f(x+\pi/2)$?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, power-series, functional-equations

Suppose $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a circular function with fundamental period $2\pi$, or else that $f$ is the zero function. In other words, assume that $f$ is of the form $$f(x) = A \sin (x) + B \cos (x).$$

Then $f$ necessarily satisfies

$$f'(x) = f(x+\pi/2). \tag{$*$}$$

> **Question.** Do there exist analytic functions not of this form satisfying $(*)$?

Note that the question is whether there exist analytic functions not of the form $x \mapsto A\sin(x)+B\cos(x)$ that nevertheless satisfy $(*)$. That is, there's no assumption of periodicity in the question.

Answer (score 5):

**Edit:** In earlier versions of the question it seemed to me the OP was assuming that $f$ has period $2\pi$. The words "That is" in the question seems to take for granted that a linear combination of $\sin$ and $\cos$ is the only $2\pi$-periodic solution. This doesn't seem quite so evident to me; I give a proof below. I doubt that there are more aperiodic analytic solutions, no proof yet.

Assuming first that $f$ does have period $2\pi$: Say $$f(t)\sim\sum c_ne^{int}.$$

The condition $f'(t)=f(t+\pi/2)$ implies that $f$ is infinitely differentiable, so there's no problem with convergence, termwise differentiation, etc. So $f'(t)=f(t+\pi/2)$ says exactly $$inc_n=e^{in\pi/2}c_n.$$If you look at the absolute value of both sides you see $$c_n=0\quad(|n|\ne1).$$So $$f(t)=c_1e^{it}+c_{-1}e^{-it}=A\sin(t)+B\cos(t).$$

Comment: I like this solution (for the assume-periodic case) better than mine. Definitely shows off the value of Fourier series nicely.

Comment: What does the $c$ mean in the subscript of $C^∞_c((0,\pi/2))$?

Comment: @goblin The support of $\phi$ is a compact subset of  $(0,\pi/2)$. (Hence $\phi$ vanishes in a nbd of $0$ and a nbd of $\pi/2$, so there's no problem patching together translates of  derivatives of  $\phi$ to get a $C^\infty$ function $f$.)

Comment: Right. You can give some kind of direction for proving your exercise? If I understand correctly, we can differentiate $\phi$ and then shift it left by $\pi/2$ to get the next patch of $f$. This allows us to cover the left-half of the real line by patches whose union will eventually become $f$. I don't understand how we construct the right-half of $f$, however.

Comment: @goblin The exercise was wrong.  In one direction we use derivatives, in the other direction we use antiderivatives, and we can't get all the anntiderivatives to have the right support.

Comment: I think this proof (or a modest modification thereof) also gives that the result holds for holomorphic functions, too, since Taylor and Fourier series are so closely related.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich, I thought that might be the case. I guess one possibility is to look for very specific $\phi$'s that go both above and below the $x$-axis so that the final integral is $0$, and whose antiderivatives also have this property. I don't know if such functions exist.

Comment: @goblin What you guess is the right thing to guess, but it don't work. To get all the antiderivvatives with compact support in $(0,\pi/2)$ we need $\int t^n\phi(t)=0$ for every $n\ge0$, and since $\phi$ has compact support that implies $\phi=0$.

Comment: @CameronWilliams Praps - I don't see how, exactly.

Answer (score 2):

If you apply the starred result four times, you arrive at
$$
f''''(x) = f(x + 2\pi) = f(x),
$$
so we can solve $f''''(x) = f(x)$ as a start to finding all possible solutions to the original equation (and some spurious ones as well).

I haven't had my morning caffeine yet, so I can't write down all solutions of that off the top of my head. Maybe linear combinations of $e^{bx}$, where $b$ is a fourth root of unity? I think that's right.

Clearly two of those (for $b = i$) give you sines and cosines. Ah...and the other two are $e^x$ and $e^{-x}$, which aren't periodic.

So a function satisfying (*) is a linear combination of $\sin(x), \cos(x)$, $\exp(x)$, and $\exp(-x)$. If it's periodic, then the coefficients of the last two are zero, and it must be a combination of sine and cosine, and we're done.

Comment: Right, but I mean there's no a priori guarantee that $f(x+2\pi) = f(x)$, right?

Comment: @goblin You _said_ you were asking about functions with period $1$. Then when you gave that example it became clear that you meant period $2\pi$. The  a priori guarantee that $f$ has period  $2\pi$ come from a generous reading of the question...

Comment: Ah...well, I seem to have mis-read your question, thinking that we were working within a specific category, while you wanted to work in...some unspecified larger category. Oh, well. I still find my answer interesting, so I'm leaving it.

Comment: Sorry, obviously I meant $2\pi$. I think this answer makes an interesting point, but doesn't fully answer my intended question.

Comment: I figured you meant $2\pi$ when you said "fundamental period 1"; I just guessed that the factor of $2\pi$ was part of your text's (or field's) definition of "fundamental period," sorta the way some physicists say that the speed of light is $1$. :)

Comment: Why do you say he meant the question in some larger category? Modulo $2\pi =1$ your answer looks correct to me...

Comment: Right...I meant that OP was asking about (as it turns out) analytic functions on the reals, rather than periodic functions.

Comment: ??? The first sentence specifies period $2\pi$.

Comment: I think the form of the intended question was "Among certain periodic functions, we observe THIS holds; are there any other analytic functions (not necessarily periodic) for which this *also* holds?" I grant you that it was not very clearly written. It's been somewhat improved by the edit.

Comment: @JohnHughes, how would you suggest writing it?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich, so, to clarify, the first sentence specifies period $2\pi$ instead of $1$ because originally I wrote $1$, then fixed it later. The intended meaning of the question is whether there exist analytic functions $f$ not of the form $x \mapsto A \sin(x) + B \sin(x)$ that nevertheless have the property $f'(x) = f(x+\pi/2)$. So, no periodicity assumption. But I still think the partial solution in which periodicity is assumed is interesting, and might even point the way towards a full solution.

Comment: Care to check your work: $(e^x)'\ne e^{x+\pi/2}$ !!!

Comment: i agree. But I was solving the derived equation $f'''' = f$, for which $f(x) = e^x$ *is* a solution. Not every solution to the derived equation will solve the original (evidently!). But all solutions to the original will be solutions to the derived one, so if solutions to the latter are easy to find, why not do so and eliminate the bad ones (as I did)? I've edited to clarify that this was what I was doing.

Comment: @goblin: I'd rewrite the question by saying "The period-$2\pi$ functions of the form $f(x) = A\sin x + B \cos x$ all satisfy $f'(x) = f(x + \pi/2)$. Are there any other functions in $C^1(\Bbb R)$ that satisfy this same equation?"  (To be honest, I'd have written it the way you did, and then edited when I realized it was misleading folks...)